# Android how to evaluate view size to keep same proportion in all devices

Tags: android, view, resize, screen, device

I'm searching for a way to keep view size proportioned on all devices. I experimented with many maths calculations (e.g. mixing screen size, density, percentage, etc.) but haven't found any solutions, just different results for each device tested.

Let me present an example: Suppose I'm testing an app on a sw-360dp and eventually I find a size view that works.

```
relativeLayoutParams.width  = 150;

relativeLayoutParams.height = 250;
```

This has the effect of creating a view with size about 1/3 of screen width and 1/2 screen height.

How can I dynamically arrive at value for width and height, that lets the view keep the aspect ratio of 1/3 width to 1/2 height?  At least I think that's what the documentation is suggesting when it says: "calculate exact view size (or margin, padding, etc.) from a percentage of screen size".

Or have I misinterpreted it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Simply reason in **dp**s instead of pixels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the device screen size and there by define the ratio,

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
```

Then,

```
    width = (int) size.x * 1/3 ; 
    height = (int) size.y * 1/2 ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just a question: does this solution work fine independently by screen density?

Comment: yes it is, i have test it. also accept the answer if it helped you.